How I can run code analysis in .NET 6 / 8 application on Debug -> Start
I'm trying to configure my .NET 6 / 8 projects to run code analysis also on Debug => Start Debugging (F5) or Debug => Start Without Debugging (ctrl+F5) , but I can't do that.
Writing something wrong in my code and than running the command Project => Build/Rebuild the build fails due to the errors shown in the Error List Panel on VS (or on command line) as I expect.
The same wrong lines doesn't stop the Debug command.
In the .csproj I set
<AnalysisLevel>latest-recommended</AnalysisLevel>
<AnalysisMode>all</AnalysisMode>

Can anyone help me figure out the problem? Am I missing any configuration?
I've tried to find out a configuration or a specific command on learn.microsoft.com but without any suggestions.
edit:
Here some information in order to reproduce the problem

Visual Studio 2022 v. 17.9.6
New Project Console application .NET 8
Install nuget package StyleCop.Analyzers 1.2.0-beta.556
new local file .editorconfig with the following configuration

root = true
[*.{cs}]
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1507.severity = error # Code should not contain multiple blank lines in a row


in program.cs add two lines above Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


Have you tried setting <RunAnalyzers>true</RunAnalyzers> and/or <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild> in your csproj?

@Lennart tested just right now without success

It seems that it's necessary to enable "Treat warnings as error" for the project, either by setting it in the project settings or adding it via <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors> to the csproj.
Otherwise the build fails, but the debugger can still be started. I assume the debugger only cares about actual compiler errors, and not errors emitted by analyzers otherwise. This will fail the build on all warnings however, even those only set to warning in .editorconfig.
